# Export to PDF not working for second form in YII

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have 2 tables for listing in page. For each table we can generate PDF. It is working fine for me but when i click on second table's PDF then it shows me first table's data instead of second table's data how can i solve this problem, 
 Below is my code 
First Table view code :-

```
<div class="span-24">
<div style="width: 100%; height: 2px; background: #999999; margin-top: 5px;" ></div>
  <div class="span-24" style="margin-top: 5px">
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left;"> <a class="create" href="#" id="going"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View On Going Project')?></a> </span>
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left"> <a class="create" href="#" id="compeleted"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View Compeleted Project')?></a> </span>
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left"> <a class="create" href="#" id="pending"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View Pending Project')?></a> </span>
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left;border: none"> <a class="create" href="#" id="canceled"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View Canceled Project')?></a> </span>
    <?php
                 $this->widget('ActionsWidget', array(
                'data' => $model,
                'template' => '{create}',
                //'createButtonUrl' => 'array("procurement/create","id" => '.$id.')',
                'createButtonVisible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("createProject")',
                'createButtonLabel' => Yii::t('app','New Project')
            ));
            ?>
  </div>
  <div class="span-24">

    <?php

$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'project-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
));

$this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array(

    'id' => 'project-grid',
    'title' => 'Export Project ' . date('Ymd'),
    'filename' => 'Export Project ' . date('Ymd'),
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'dataProvider' => $model->latestProject(),
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id, data){
        jQuery('#Project_start_date_1').datepicker({'altField':'#Project_start_date','altFormat':'yy-mm-dd','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});
        jQuery('#Project_end_date_1').datepicker({'altField':'#Project_end_date','altFormat':'yy-mm-dd','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});
        jQuery('#Project_status').multiselect({
            selectedList: 2
        });
    }",
    'filter' => $model,
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id, data){
        jQuery('#Project_start_date_1').datepicker({'altField':'#Project_start_date','altFormat':'yy-mm-dd','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});
        jQuery('#Project_end_date_1').datepicker({'altField':'#Project_end_date','altFormat':'yy-mm-dd','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});
    }",
    'columns' => array(
        'project_no',
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'html',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return CHtml::link($data->name, array('project/view', 'id' => $data->id));
             }
        ),
        array(

            'name' => 'scope_of_project',
            'type' => 'html',
            'value' => '$data->scope_of_project',
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->params['project']['scope_of_project'],
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'inspector_id',
            'type' => 'html',
            'filter' => $model->getInspectorList(),
            'value' => function($data)
            {
                return $data->inspector->name." ".$data->inspector->surname;
            },
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->params['project']['inspector_id'],
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'ext.myGridView.MyButtonColumn',
            'buttons' => array(
                'update' => array('visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("updateProject")'),
                'delete' => array('visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("deleteProject")'),               
            ),
            'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("project/update",array("id" => $data->id))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("project/delete",array("id" => $data->id))',
            'viewButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("project/view",array("id" => $data->id))',
            'header'=>CHtml::dropDownList(
                'pageSize',
                Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize'),
                array(""=>Yii::t('app','Page Size'),5=>5,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100),
                array('class'=>'change-pagesize')
            ),
        ),
      /*
          array(
          'name' => 'created_by',
          'filter' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'username')), 'id', 'username'),
          'value' => '$data->creator->username'
          ), 
        array(
            'header' =>  Yii::t('app', 'Open Tasks'),
            'value' => function ($data) {
        return Task::model()->public()->count(array('select' => 'id', 'condition' => 'par_project_id = :pid AND status IN (:open, :wip)', 'params' => array('pid' => $data->id, 'open' => 1, 'wip' => 2)));
    }
        ),
        array(
            'header' => Yii::t('app', 'All Tasks'),
            'value' => function ($data) {
        return Task::model()->public()->count(array('select' => 'id', 'condition' => 'par_project_id = :pid', 'params' => array('pid' => $data->id)));
    }
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'status', Project::model()->getStatusList(), array('multiple' => true, 'style' => 'display:none')),
            'value' => '$data->getStatus()',
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'ext.myGridView.MyButtonColumn',
            'buttons' => array(
                'update' => array('visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("updateProject")'),
                'delete' => array('visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("deleteProject")'),
            ),
        ),

    ),
));

$this->endWidget();
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initPageSize','
    $(".change-pagesize").live("change", function() {
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("project-grid",{ data:{ pageSize: $(this).val() }})
    });'
,CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second table view code

```
<div class="span-24">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 2px; background: #999999; margin-top: 5px;" ></div>
  <div class="span-24" style="margin-top: 5px">
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left"> <a class="create" href="#" id="paid"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View Paid Expenses')?></a> </span>
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left"> <a class="create" href="#" id="onGoing"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View On Going Expenses')?></a> </span>
    <span id="yw4" class="actionstab" style="float:left;border: none;"> <a class="create" href="#" id="unpaid"><?php echo Yii::t('app','View Pending Expenses')?></a> </span>
    <?php
                $this->widget('ActionsWidget', array(
                'data' => $model,
                'template' => '{create}',
                //'createButtonUrl' => 'array("procurement/create","id" => '.$id.')',
                'createButtonVisible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("createExpenses")',
                'createButtonLabel' => Yii::t('app','New Expenses')
                ));
                ?>
  </div>
  <div class="span-24">
    <?php
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'expenses-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
));

$this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array(
    'title' => 'Export Expenses ' . date('Ymd'),
    'filename' => 'Export Expenses ' . date('Ymd'),
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'id'=>'expenses-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id, data){
        jQuery('#Expenses_added_date_1').datepicker({'altField':'#Expenses_added_date','altFormat':'yy-mm-dd','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});
        jQuery('#Expenses_payment_date_1').datepicker({'altField':'#Expenses_payment_date','altFormat':'yy-mm-dd','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'});

    }",
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        array(
            'header' => Yii::t("app","Project"),
            'name' => "project_id",
            'filter' => $model->getProjectList(),
            'value' => function($data)
            {
                return $data->project->name;
            }
        ),
        'invoice_no',

         array(
            'name' => 'added_date',
            'type' => 'date',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeHiddenField($model, 'added_date') . $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name' => 'Expenses[added_date_1]',
                'value' => $model->added_date == null ? '' : Yii::app()->format->date($model->added_date),
                'options' => array(
                    'altField' => '#Expenses_added_date',
                    'altFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
                    'defaultDate' => $model->added_date == null ? '' : Yii::app()->format->date($model->added_date),
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'size' => '10',
                    'maxlength' => '10',
                    'onchange' => 'if(this.value==="") $("#Expenses_added_date").val("");'
                ),
                    ), true),
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'col-date')
        ),
        'amount',
        array(
            'name' => 'paid_status',
            'filter' => $model->getPaidList(),
            'value' => function($data)
            {
                if($data->paid_status == 1)
                {
                    return Yii::t("app","Paid");
                }
                else if($data->paid_status == 0)
                {
                    return Yii::t("app","Unpaid");
                }
                else if($data->paid_status == 2)
                {
                    return Yii::t("app","On Going");
                }
            },
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->params['expenses']['paid_status'],
        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'payment_date',
            'type' => 'date',
            'filter' => CHtml::activeHiddenField($model, 'payment_date') . $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name' => 'Expenses[payment_date_1]',
                'value' => $model->added_date == null ? '' : Yii::app()->format->date($model->payment_date),
                'options' => array(
                    'altField' => '#Expenses_payment_date',
                    'altFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                    'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
                    'defaultDate' => $model->payment_date == null ? '' : Yii::app()->format->date($model->payment_date),
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'size' => '10',
                    'maxlength' => '10',
                    'onchange' => 'if(this.value==="") $("#Expenses_payment_date").val("");'
                ),
                    ), true),
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'col-date'),
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->params['expenses']['payment_date'],
        ),
        array(  
            'name' => 'description',
            'type' => 'html',
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->params['expenses']['status'],
        ),
        //'attachment',
        array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'filter' => $model->getStatusList(),
            'value' => '$data->status == 1 ? Yii::t("app","Active") : Yii::t("app","Deactive")',
            'visible'=>Yii::app()->params['expenses']['status'],
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'ext.myGridView.MyButtonColumn',
            'buttons' => array(
                'update' => array('visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("updateProject")'),
                'delete' => array('visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->checkAccess("deleteProject")'),
            ),
            'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("expenses/update",array("id" => $data->id))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("expenses/delete",array("id" => $data->id))',
            'viewButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("expenses/view",array("id" => $data->id))',
            'header'=>CHtml::dropDownList(
                'pageSize',
                Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize'),
                array(""=>Yii::t('app','Page Size'),5=>5,20=>20,50=>50,100=>100),
                array('class'=>'change-pagesize1')
            ),
        ),


    ),
));
$this->endWidget();
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initPageSize1','
    $(".change-pagesize1").live("change", function() {
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update("expenses-grid",{ data:{ pageSize: $(this).val() }})
    });'
,CClientScript::POS_READY);
?>
  </div>
</div>
```

PDF generation file :

```
<?php

Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');
class EExcelView extends CGridView {

    //Document properties
    public $creator = 'Nikola Kostadinov';
    public $title = null;
    public $subject = 'Subject';
    public $description = '';
    public $category = '';
    private $_lastRow = 0;
    //the PHPExcel object
    public $objPHPExcel = null;
    public $libPath = 'ext.PHPExcel.Classes.PHPExcel'; //the path to the PHP excel lib
    //config
    public $autoWidth = true;
    public $exportType = 'Excel5';
    public $disablePaging = true;
    public $filename = null; //export FileName
    public $stream = true; //stream to browser
    public $grid_mode = 'grid'; //Whether to display grid ot export it to selected format. Possible values(grid, export)
    public $grid_mode_var = 'grid_mode'; //GET var for the grid mode
    //buttons config
    public $exportButtonsCSS = 'export-buttons';
    public $exportButtons = array('Excel2007', 'CSV', 'HTML','PDF');
    public $exportText = 'Export to:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    //callbacks
    public $onRenderHeaderCell = null;
    public $onRenderDataCell = null;
    public $onRenderFooterCell = null;
    //mime types used for streaming
    public $mimeTypes = array(
        'Excel5' => array(
            'Content-type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'extension' => 'xls',
            'caption' => 'Excel',
            'icon' => 'images/actions/excel.png',
        ),
        'Excel2007' => array(
            'Content-type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'extension' => 'xlsx',
            'caption' => 'Excel',
            'icon' => 'images/actions/excel.png',
        ),
        'PDF' => array(
            'Content-type' => 'application/pdf',
            'extension' => 'pdf',
            'caption' => 'PDF(*.pdf)',
            'icon' => 'images/actions/pdf.png',
        ),
        'HTML' => array(
            'Content-type' => 'text/html',
            'extension' => 'html',
            'caption' => 'HTML',
            'icon' => 'images/actions/html.png',
        ),

        'CSV' => array(
            'Content-type' => 'application/csv',
            'extension' => 'csv',
            'caption' => 'CSV',
            'icon' => 'images/actions/csv.png',
        )
    );

    public function init() {
        if (isset($_GET[$this->grid_mode_var]))
            $this->grid_mode = $_GET[$this->grid_mode_var];
        if (isset($_GET['exportType']))
            $this->exportType = $_GET['exportType'];
        $this->template = "{summary}\n{items}\n{exportbuttons}"; //\n{pager}";
        $this->creator = Yii::app()->params['name'];
        array_unshift($this->columns, array(
            'id' => 'chkId',
            'name' => 'chkId',
            'value' => '$data->id',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn'
        ));
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('no-row-selection', '
            $(document).on("click.yiiGridView", ".grid-view td:not(\'.checkbox-column\')", function(){$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");});
            $(document).on("click.yiiGridView", ".grid-view .button-column", function(){$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");});
            $(document).on("click.yiiGridView", ".grid-view .filters", function(){$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");});
        ');

        $lib = Yii::getPathOfAlias($this->libPath) . '.php';
        if ($this->grid_mode == 'export' and !file_exists($lib)) {
            $this->grid_mode = 'grid';
            Yii::log("PHP Excel lib not found($lib). Export disabled !", CLogger::LEVEL_WARNING, 'EExcelview');
        }

        if ($this->grid_mode == 'export') {
            $this->title = $this->title ? $this->title : Yii::app()->getController()->getPageTitle();
            $this->initColumns();
            //parent::init();
            //Autoload fix
            spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
            Yii::import($this->libPath, true);
            $this->objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            PHPExcel_Shared_File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true);
            spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
            // Creating a workbook
            $this->objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator($this->creator);
            $this->objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle($this->title);
            $this->objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject($this->subject);
            $this->objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription($this->description);
            $this->objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCategory($this->category);
        }
        else
            parent::init();
    }

    public function renderHeader() {
        $a = 0;
        foreach ($this->columns as $column) {
            if ($column instanceof CButtonColumn)
//                $head = $column->header;
                continue;
            elseif ($column instanceof CCheckBoxColumn)
                continue;
            elseif ($column->header === null && $column->name !== null) {
                if ($column->grid->dataProvider instanceof CActiveDataProvider)
                    $head = $column->grid->dataProvider->model->getAttributeLabel($column->name);
                else
                    $head = $column->name;
            }
            else
                $head = trim($column->header) !== '' ? $column->header : $column->grid->blankDisplay;

            $a++;
            $cell = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($this->columnName($a) . "1", $head, true);
            if (is_callable($this->onRenderHeaderCell))
                call_user_func_array($this->onRenderHeaderCell, array($cell, $head));
        }
    }

    public function renderBody() {
        if ($this->disablePaging) //if needed disable paging to export all data
            $this->dataProvider->pagination = false;

        $data = $this->dataProvider->getData();
        $n = count($data);

        $chkIdAll = isset($_POST['chkId']) ? $_POST['chkId'] : array();

        if (count($chkIdAll) > 0 && $n > 0) {
            for ($row = 0; $row < $n; ++$row) {
                if (in_array(CHtml::value($data[$row], 'id'), $chkIdAll))
                    $this->renderRow($row);
            }
        }
        return $n;
    }

    public function renderRow($row) {
        $data = $this->dataProvider->getData();

        $a = 0;
        foreach ($this->columns as $n => $column) {
            if ($column instanceof CLinkColumn) {
                if ($column->labelExpression !== null)
                    $value = $column->evaluateExpression($column->labelExpression, array('data' => $data[$row], 'row' => $row));
                else
                    $value = $column->label;
            } elseif ($column instanceof CButtonColumn)
//                $value = ""; //Dont know what to do with buttons
                continue;
            elseif ($column instanceof CCheckBoxColumn)
                continue;
            elseif ($column->value !== null)
                $value = $this->evaluateExpression($column->value, array('data' => $data[$row]));
            elseif ($column->name !== null) {
                //$value=$data[$row][$column->name];
                $value = CHtml::value($data[$row], $column->name);
                $value = $value === null ? '' : $column->grid->getFormatter()->format($value, 'raw');
            }

            $a++;
            $cell = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($this->columnName($a) . ($this->_lastRow + 2), strip_tags($value), true);
            if (is_callable($this->onRenderDataCell))
                call_user_func_array($this->onRenderDataCell, array($cell, $data[$row], $value));
        }
        $this->_lastRow++;
    }

    public function renderFooter($row) {
        $a = 0;
        foreach ($this->columns as $n => $column) {
            $a = $a + 1;
            if ($column->footer) {
                $footer = trim($column->footer) !== '' ? $column->footer : $column->grid->blankDisplay;

                $cell = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($this->columnName($a) . ($row + 2), $footer, true);
                if (is_callable($this->onRenderFooterCell))
                    call_user_func_array($this->onRenderFooterCell, array($cell, $footer));
            }
        }
    }

    public function run() {
        if ($this->grid_mode == 'export') {
            $this->renderHeader();
            $row = $this->renderBody();
            $this->renderFooter($this->_lastRow);

            //set auto width
            if ($this->autoWidth)
                foreach ($this->columns as $n => $column)
                    if (!($column instanceof CButtonColumn || $column instanceof CCheckBoxColumn))
                    $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($this->columnName($n))->setAutoSize(false);

            $lastColumnIndex = 0;
            foreach ($this->columns as $column)
                if (!($column instanceof CButtonColumn || $column instanceof CCheckBoxColumn))
                    $lastColumnIndex++;

            $lastColumnName = $this->columnName($lastColumnIndex);
            $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:' . $lastColumnName . ++$this->_lastRow)
                    ->applyFromArray(array(
                        'borders' => array(
                            'allborders' => array(
                                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                            )
                        )
            ));
            $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:' . $lastColumnName . '1')
                    ->applyFromArray(array(
                        'alignment' => array(
                            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                            'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                            'rotation' => 0,
                            'wrap' => TRUE
                        ),
                        'fill' => array(
                            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                            'rotation' => 270,
                            'startcolor' => array(
                                'rgb' => '6FACCF'
                            ),
                            'endcolor' => array(
                                'rgb' => 'A8CDE2'
                            )
                        ),
                        'font' => array(
                            'bold' => true,
                            'color' => array(
                                'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                            )
                        )
            ));
            for ($i = 2; $i <= $this->_lastRow; $i++)
                $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $i . ':' . $lastColumnName . $i)
                        ->applyFromArray(array(
                            'fill' => array(
                                'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                                'color' => array(
                                    'rgb' => $i % 2 === 0 ? 'E5F1F4' : 'F8F8F8'
                                ),
                            ),
                ));

            //create writer for saving
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, $this->exportType);
            if (!$this->stream)
                $objWriter->save($this->filename);
            else { //output to browser
                if (!$this->filename)
                    $this->filename = $this->title;
                $this->cleanOutput();
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-type: ' . $this->mimeTypes[$this->exportType]['Content-type']);
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $this->filename . '.' . $this->mimeTypes[$this->exportType]['extension'] . '"');
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
                $objWriter->save('php://output');
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
        }
        else
            parent::run();
    }
    public function columnName($index) {
        --$index;
        if ($index >= 0 && $index < 26)
            return chr(ord('A') + $index);
        else if ($index > 25)
            return ($this->columnName($index / 26)) . ($this->columnName($index % 26 + 1));
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid Column # " . ($index + 1));
    }

    public function renderExportButtons() {

        foreach ($this->exportButtons as $key => $button) {
            $item = is_array($button) ? CMap::mergeArray($this->mimeTypes[$key], $button) : $this->mimeTypes[$button];
            $type = is_array($button) ? $key : $button;
//            $url = parse_url(Yii::app()->request->requestUri);
            //$content[] = CHtml::link($item['caption'], '?'.$url['query'].'exportType='.$type.'&'.$this->grid_mode_var.'=export');
//            $content = array();
//            if (key_exists('query', $url))
//                $content[] = CHtml::link($item['caption'], '?' . $url['query'] . '&exportType=' . $type . '&' . $this->grid_mode_var . '=export');
//            else
//                $content[] = CHtml::link($item['caption'], '?exportType=' . $type . '&' . $this->grid_mode_var . '=export');
            $submitParams = array(Yii::app()->controller->action->id, 'exportType' => $type, 'grid_mode' => 'export');
            foreach ($_GET as $param => $value)
                $submitParams[$param] = $value;
            $content[] = CHtml::link($item['caption'] . ' ' . CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/' . $item['icon'], '', array('width' => 16, 'height' => 16)), '#', array('submit' => $submitParams));
        }
        if ($content) {
//            echo CHtml::tag('div', array('class' => $this->exportButtonsCSS), $this->exportText . implode('&nbsp;', $content) . $this->renderPager());
            echo '<div class="excel-footer">';
            $this->renderPager();
            echo '<div class="', $this->exportButtonsCSS, '">';
            echo $this->exportText . implode('&nbsp;', $content);
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    protected static function cleanOutput() {
        for ($level = ob_get_level(); $level > 0; --$level) {
            @ob_end_clean();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have same problem. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the extension calls the same URL and when the grid builds it checks for the exportgrid param and does the export but there is no grid-id involved so the first grid "catches" the event and exports the result.

A possible solution is to remove buttons from rendering in the template(second grid only)

```
'template'=>"{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}"
```

After that generate you own buttons linking to action that has this code:

```
$this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array(
 ... copy all the values from the view .....
);
```

Or a much better solution would be to extract the second view to a partial view. So in the above action you could just render this partial and the "magic" will happen :)

The export buttons must end with so that the grid "knows" that has to export the data

```
?exportType='.$type.'&grid_mode=export
```

Where $type is the type of export e.g. Excel5

**UPDATE**
I wouldnt recommend updating the extension as Manisha Patel stated below. The soulution is to set different export vars to each of the grids :

```
$this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array( 'grid_mode_var' => 'grid1_export' .....Other Variable of the gird));
```

After that the extensions will render proper links with the new vars or if you manually render the links then you need to put that grid_mode_var in the url like this :

```
?exportType=XXXXX&grid1_export=export
```

Where "grid1_export" is the name of the var set via config.

Comment: Both grid views are in a partial page.But still not resolved it.Please provide me any other hint.

Comment: the hint is that whichever grid renders first will export the data beacuse of the get param grid_mode=export. Oh wait, you can set the export grid var via config.

    $this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array(
     'grid_mode_var' => 'grid1_export'
    );

for the first grid .

Comment: Yes thats works.But in this case now second grid view data are downloading in both girdview. Can we separate it any other way. It really very helpful

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem with this solution ? Can you clarify?

Comment: i want download the data of both gird view. When i do this $this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array( 'grid_mode_var' => 'grid1_export' ); at that timr second girdview data is downloaded nice but when i am trying for first one it will download second gridview data. So basically i want to download the data of both girdview with its own data.

Comment: You want to download both grids with a single export ? If that is the case that is not possible. You can download only one grid at a time.

Comment: let me explain in details: There two grid view 1. Project 2.Expense when i am trying to download the data of expense then it will download the data of project and i have tried to change the gird_mode also but at the time when i trying to download the project data then it will download the data of the expense. So i want that project should download project data and expenses should download expense data. Right now only one gird view data is download in both grid view downloading.

Comment: Ok, if you set grid mode var via config then you need to modify the link, for example grid1 : 
$this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array( 'grid_mode_var' => 'grid1_export' )
And the link will be : /myt/site/index?exportType=Excel2007&grid1_export=export

For the second grid is the same but with grid2_export and link /myt/site/index?exportType=Excel2007&grid2_export=export

Comment: Okay let me try for this

Answer (score 0):

With help of the Nikola I have finally got the solution of the problem and the answer of this problem in two step which below:

1. Change the variable grid_mode_var in Gird view as explained by Nikola like below

   $this->widget('ext.EExcelView', array( 'grid_mode_var' => 'grid1_export'
                   .....Other Variable of the gird));
2. Change the path of downloading attribute as said by Nikola like below:
   1.Got to extenstion/EExcelView.php
   2.Find function renderExportButtons.
   3.Once You find that then change the line:  $submitParams = array(Yii::app()->controller->action->id, 'exportType' => $type, 'grid_mode' => 'export'); **to** $submitParams = array(Yii::app()->controller->action->id, 'exportType' => $type, $this->grid_mode_var => 'export');